# How to modify OpenVPN internal routing table directly?

Tags: routing, openvpn

On OpenVPN (v2.4) server side, when you want to route a network to a specific client, you add `route` directive to server config file (adds route to system routing table) and `iroute` directive to client config file in **ccd** directory (adds route to OpenVPN internal routing table). However, if the client is already connected, it needs to disconnect and reconnect in order for route to become active. I'd like to know if there is a way to activate the route without dropping client connection. Adding a route to system routing table is easy enough, but I can't find a way to modify OpenVPN internal routing table. If it's not possible, it would be useful to know.

EDIT: Apparently there is no way to do this. I've put up a [feature request](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/1046) on OpenVPN bug tracker.